# Wizard performs an automatic click when the second step shows up

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, client

I'm currently using twitter bootstrap wizard as this [template](https://themesbrand.com/minia/layouts/form-wizard.html), so my wizard structure is something like:

```
form
  step1
    inputs
    button next
  step2
    inputs
    button next
  step3
  submit
```

Code:

```
//first step
<div class="tab-pane step" id="progress-station-profile">
//fields here

   <button onclick="return validate('progress-station-profile')" 
   class="btn btn-primary">
    Next
   </button>
</div>

//Step 2

 <div class="tab-pane step" id="progress-station-owner">
  //fields here

  <button onclick="return validate('progress-station-owner')"  
   class="btn btn-primary">
    Next
   </button>
 </div>

//Step 3

 //fields
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1"> Save Station</button>
```

JS:

```
function validate(step){
    let window = document.getElementById(step);

    window.querySelectorAll("input,select,textarea").forEach(e=>{
      if(!e.checkValidity()){

        e.classList.toggle("is-invalid");
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }
    });
    return true;
  }
```

As you can see, I use validate function to perform the client validation on each step, so it works, it does not allow you to go to the next step if you find a missing validation.

The problem starts when it goes to the second step; for some reason, it automatically performs the click action on the next button, so it throws the validations when the second step shows up. Why is it performing a click when the form shows up? I know it is a problem with my function because if I disable it, the problem does not happen, but I can not found why

Comment: have you tried using callback function for the onClick action on btn?

Comment: Nop, what d you mean?, ooh you mean to call it like this: `onclick="validate('progress-station-owner')"`, yes I tried, but was the same result @riskylast